# Change Operator's icon depending of key pressed

Tags: interface, operator

I have an operator that when clicked, makes A, and when clicked while holding CTRL, makes B.

In order to make this more intuitive and easier for the user, I'd like to detect on the `draw()` method when the CTRL key is pressed, and if so, change the icon.

Is that possible?